# For /F (/w findstr) command only opens .TXT file

Tags: batch-file

I want to use for /f to read through a txt. file with findstr. But it only 
 opens the txt file, if i remove the (') my piping doesnt work.

```
set PATH_TEMPTXT=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Temp_txt.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('%PATH_TEMPTXT% ^| findstr "Files:"') do (
        set F_Files=%%b
        echo TEST   FILES           %%b
    )

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('%PATH_TEMPTXT% ^| findstr "Size:"') do (
        set F_Size=%%b
        echo TEST   SIZE            %%b
    )


echo FILES              %F_Files%
echo SIZE               %F_Size%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the txt File:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 929654 bytes (908 KiB)

Extracting archive: C:\Users\User\Downloads\test\DIEZIP.7z
--
Path = C:\Users\User\Downloads\test\DIEZIP.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 929654
Headers Size = 1953
Method = LZMA2:23
Solid = +
Blocks = 5

Everything is Ok

Folders: 20
Files: 129
Size:       15270523
Compressed: 929654
```

I want the File Count (129) and the Size (15270523)

EDIT How I get my temp_txt

FYI:The script copies a list of files / directories from a source to a destination directory using 7ZIP
The files are packed and unpacked at the destination

```
REM unzip
:: set Path for temp_txt
set PATH_TEMPTXT=%SOURCE_PATH%\Temp_txt.txt
:: get temp txt with copied files and size
:: I unzip my zip and direct the output into my temp_txt so I can get the filescount and size with the code above
%PATH_7Z% x -y -o%f_ziel% %PATH_ZIP% > %PATH_TEMPTXT%
```

Comment: `findstr "Files:" "%PATH_TEMPTXT%"`

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "Files:" "%PATH_TEMPTXT%"')` worked thanks

Comment: You don't think the contents of all your variables you are using are pertinent to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can parse output with the `FINDSTR` command.  You can PIPE, REDIRECT or list the file directly.  You are not piping correctly.  You need to use the `TYPE` command with the file name to PIPE it to `FINDSTR`. One caveat of piping is that it is slower than redirection or accessing the file directly.

Regardless of all that, this code simplifies your existing code.

```
@echo off
set PATH_TEMPTXT=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_txt.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /B "Files: Size:" "%PATH_TEMPTXT%"') do (
    set F_%%a=%%b
)

echo FILES              %F_Files%
echo SIZE               %F_Size%
pause
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Would it be possible to do that without my TEMPTXT? Right now I create TEMPTXT like this: REM unzip
`set PATH_TEMPTXT=%SOURCE_PATH%\Temp_txt.txt`
REM get temp txt with copied files and size
`%PATH_7Z% x -y -o%f_ziel% %PATH_ZIP% > %PATH_TEMPTXT%`

Comment: @RjuJBong, I cannot decipher your code in your comments.  Feel free to edit your question and format the code properly.  Then maybe I might understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could place everything inside of the `for /F` loop, like this: `for /F "..." %%a in ('7z.exe x -y ... ^| findstr /B "..."') do ( ... )`